# Make particles stick to emitter, then separate

Tags: particles, physics, force-fields

I would like to animate the removal of dust from an object. Is it possible to make "dust" particles stick to the emitter object untill a certain time, then seperate them from the emitter all at once via a force field (curve guide)?

Here is how I would like the object with dust to look like (Physics type set to keyed here):
[image: pill with dust]

I tried giving these pills their own force field and getting particles to stick to their surface from a seperate emitter, then setting up another force field where they would separate but it looks weird. What would be the cleanest way to do this?

Comment: Maybe you should cut or keyframe the Field Weights > Gravity and the Velocity > Normal?

Answer (score 0):

Create your particle system with *Frame Start* and *End* at 0. Put the *Velocity > Normal* at 0 and the *Field Weights > Gravity* at 0. Create a *Force Field > Wind* and a *Turbulence*. Keyframe their *Strength* so that they start to act at the frame you want. Play:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, the issue with this method is that my object is moving (rigid body affected by physics). Particles don't stick to the object when it's moving.

Comment: oh yes that makes it more complicated, maybe you need to cheat with some tricks, like make the particles real, then make them invisible and begin the simulation on another particle system?